# PySpark Perform 2 separate write operations on same dataframe without recomputation

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write the same dataframe to two different locations, but the dataframe is recomputed even if I persist the dataframe beforehand. How can I change this so that the dataframe is only computed once even though I do 2 separate write actions?

```py
df.persist()
df.write.mode("overwrite").csv(file_path_1)
df.write.mode("overwrite").csv(file_path_2)
```

Comment: In general, If you cache it - the initial line will store it in cache only after some action, so the calculation will created once. the write itself is just writing files so imagian that your dataframe is saved on multiple executors each executor will initiate tasks and will just persist the data from its memory once again in different location. to summarize, your first line will cache and save the data and the second write will just use the memory location and save the precalculated data again in different location. 
messure times the second line should be faster , share logs if you can

Comment: How do you know its computed twice?

Comment: @mazaneicha Before the persist I have a transform operation that calls an AWS Lambda. The Lambda has twice the number of invocations as it should. This only started happening after I added the second write operation.

Comment: @Benny Elgazar That's what I imagined it would do. Maybe some stupid mistake in the rest of the code.

Comment: So you didn't compare `df.explain()` before each write to see how the plans are different and why the cached df can't be reused?